# zsh: setting RPROMPT using python script. RPROMPT not updating

Tags: shell, python-2.7, zsh

I am trying to set my zsh RPROMPT to display my current battery status as in [this guide](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/02/my-extravagant-zsh-prompt/).

I have written the following python script to find the current battery status and print out formatted battery status to be read by my .zshrc.

```
# Outputs current battery status formatted for use in zsh prompt.
#! /usr/bin/python2.7
# coding=UTF-8

import sys

def main():

    file = open('/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity', 'r')
    data = file.read()
    file.close()

    charge = int(data)

    if charge >= 75:
    prompt = '%{$fg[green]%} * * * *'

    elif charge < 75 and charge >= 50:
        prompt = '%{$fg[green]%}   * * *'

    elif charge < 50 and charge >= 25:
        prompt = '%{$fg[yellow]%}     * *'

    elif charge < 25:
        prompt = '%{$fg[red]%}       *'


    file = open('/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status', 'r')
    status = file.read()
    file.close()

    if status == 'Charging\n':
        prompt = prompt + '%{$fg[green]%} (+)'

    elif status == 'Unknown\n':
        prompt = prompt + '%{$fg[yellow]%} (?)'

    else:
        prompt = prompt + '%{$fg[red]%} (-)'


    sys.stdout.write(prompt)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I put this script in my path so that it can be run by simply typing 'battery'. Here's my .zshrc:

```
# The following lines were added by compinstall

zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand _complete _ignored _correct _approximate
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' ''
zstyle :compinstall filename '/home/jav/.zshrc'

autoload -Uz compinit promptinit
compinit
promptinit

# End of lines added by compinstall
# Lines configured by zsh-newuser-install
HISTFILE=~/.histfile
HISTSIZE=1000
SAVEHIST=1000
setopt autocd
bindkey -v
# End of lines configured by zsh-newuser-install


function prompt {
    echo
    echo '$ '
}


function battery_status {
    echo `battery`
}


autoload -U colors && colors
setopt promptsubst

PROMPT='%{$fg[white]%}[%n @ %M in %~]$(prompt)'
RPROMPT=$(battery_status)%{$reset_color%}
```

Altogether it displays something similar to the following.

```
[username @ hostname in ~]                                                       * * * * (-)
$
```

The asterisks represent the current battery charge and '(-)' represents whether it is charging or not. The issue is that the '* * * * (-)' should automatically update when the ac adapter is plugged in or the battery charge changes, but it doesn't. I have to 'source .zshrc' in order for it to update the battery status.

I know `RPROMPT=$(battery_status)%{$reset_color%}` should be surrounded by single quotes like this `RPROMPT='$(battery_status)%{$reset_color%}'`, but when I do that instead of my prompt displaying '* * * *(-)' it displays the literal output from the python program: "%{$fg[green]%} * * * *%{$fg[red]%} (-)"

This issue only occurs when using a python program within a shell function as in my .zshrc. Shell scripts used in the RPROMPT update correctly.

I had the python battery program log to a file every time it is run. According to the log file the battery program only runs when .zshrc is sourced, not each time a new prompt is printed to the terminal.

Since it only occurs with python programs, that makes me think it's an issue with how I'm printing the output. But seeing as the battery script isn't being run each time the prompt is displayed in the terminal, I feel it could be a mistake I made on the zsh side.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only setting the value of your prompt once. You need to reset it before each new prompt is shown. The easiest way is to use something like

```
set_prompt () {
    PROMPT='%{$fg[white]%}[%n @ %M in %~]$(prompt)'
    RPROMPT=$(battery_status)%{$reset_color%}
}
autoload add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook precmd set_prompt
```

to your `.zshrc` file.

Comment: Works like a charm! Any idea why it isn't expanding $(battery_status) when I added single quotes?

Comment: I'm not sure. It should behave the same as `PROMPT`, where `$(prompt)` is also single-quoted. Since you set the value of the two variables prior to each prompt being displayed, it's OK to use double quotes now, since it's OK for the command substitutions to expand immediately, rather than waiting until the prompt variables are expanded.